# How to sync home folders with Dropbox/Onedrive/Google Drive?

Tags: dropbox, google-apps

For some reason, I'd like to sync my home folders (that is `~`) with sync tools such as Dropbox/Onedrive/Google Drive.

However, making a symbolism link is not working. Then I found some apps while none of them actually works..

So what's the best practices here? Thanks :)

Comment: I symlink some folders into the ~/Dropbox folder and it generally works no problem. Note there are size restrictions on the free version of all those services which may be causing problems.

Comment: @agentroadkill I've tried but nothing changed, you mean you put a symbolism link in dropbox?

Comment: I'll create a more complete answer.

Comment: You can\t do all od ~ - are their some particular you want shared?

Comment: Have you considered using [Synching](https://www.syncthing.net)?  This would be easy to setup.  I would actually be hesitant to sync my entire home folder though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sync some *small* local folders using Dropbox (Google Drive seems more reluctant to this sort of thing, I have no experience using OneDrive).

To do this, `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/link` in Terminal works for me, no problem.

**Disclaimers**

- This solution is Mac (possibly *nix)-specific, see [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201893105-Dropbox-not-syncing-properly-with-folders-created-by-symbolic-links).
- This is not officially supported by Dropbox.
- Your home directory contains lots of config files I would be wary of sending via network connection at all.
- All the services you have listed have 'free' and 'premium' versions. I won't enumerate these here, but be aware of file and upload/bandwidth restrictions which will likely cause problems with this approach.

Comment: As an addendum, Dropbox recommends putting a file in the ~/Dropbox folder, then symlinking that back **out** to your local filesystem.

Comment: Also there are directories e.g. ~/Library/Caches which should not be shared  as some things will differ by machine especially also ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost.  Unfortunately OSX is not like Windows which has a clear difference between local and user data

Comment: @Mark, agreed, but I think the attempt is to link ~ to ~/Dropbox, so the machines won't have problems, other than constantly fighting to update the cache, prefs and other specific files.

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking that "Make Alias" is the equivalent to `ln -s`, and just now I found it's completely the different things..Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Unfortunately This does not work in OneDrive.